# Como fazer um SELECT mantendo a primeira coluna até acabarem os registros

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de fazer um SELECT que repetisse a primeira coluna, mas quando acabassem todos os registros alterasse o dado da primeira coluna e repetisse todos os registros novamente.

Vou dar um exemplo para ilustrar melhor, pois é complicado transcrever isso.

Quero listar para 3 pessoas todos os estádios por exemplo para cada um deles:

```
Tabela Pessoa:
Id - Identificação
1 - Fulano
2 - Ciclano
3 - Beltrano

Tabela Estadio
1 - Allianz Arena
2 - Santiago Bernabeu
3 - Camp Nou
```

SELECT desejado:

```
Id - Pessoa - Estadio
1 - Fulano - Allianz Arena
1 - Fulano - Santiago Bernabeu
1 - Fulano - Camp Nou
2 - Ciclano - Allianz Arena
2 - Ciclano - Santiago Bernabeu
2 - Fulano - Camp Nou
3 - Beltrano - Allianz Arena
3 - Beltrano - Santiago Bernabeu
3 - Beltrano - Camp Nou
```

Não tenho muita prática com SQL, então estou apanhando um pouco para fazer esse caso. O exemplo é apenas para ilustrar o problema.

Comment: Como estaria salvo esses campos do seu exemplo? Em uma única tabela? Em duas tabelas ligadas por chave estrangeira?

Comment: Então, esse é um dos pontos que estou vendo como problema. Elas são tabelas diferentes, mas não têm ligação por chave estrangeira, são totalmente independentes.

Comment: Em um contexto maior e futuro, em todos os casos acontecerá assim de todas pessoas relacionarem com todos estádios? Ou poderá haver o caso da pessoa Xunga que só será relacionado a alguns estádios e não todos?

Comment: Lancei uma resposta considerando TODOS pra TODOS, senão, vai ter que especificar as condições (como o David questionou) e tratar no where.

Comment: @DavidAlves creio que seja uma necessidade apenas pontual, mas pensando sempre em todas as pessoas se relacionarem com todos os estádios. A resposta que o Ismael e o Ricardo deram atenderam este caso. Agradeço sua ajuda também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você poderá usar a junção [`CROSS`](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx), ou seja, criar uma junção cruzada dos seus dados e com isso, conseguirá exibir TODOS os registros da tabela `estadios` para cada registro da tabela `pessoa`.

Código

```
SELECT P.ID, P.NOME, E.NOME FROM PESSOAS P
CROSS JOIN ESTADIOS E
ORDER BY P.ID
```

Comment: Perfeito, era justamente o que eu precisava. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

O que você quer fazer é o que geralmente quer evitar numa query com mais de uma tabela, um cartesiano. Você quer combinar todos os dados de **Pessoa** com **Estadio**

Basta fazer um `select` com os campos, incluindo ambas as tabelas no `from` sem juntá-las (sem fazer o `join`), assim:

```
select id, identificacao, descricaoEstadio
from Pessoa, Estadio
order by id, identificacao
```

Veja o exemplo nos sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d070e/3

Comment: Muito obrigado. Funcionou realmente da maneira que eu precisava.